# Prevent selection of element on click in multiple select box

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a multiple select box that is folded by default, i.e. the only element visible is the first element and it gets unfolded by javascript when I click on it. The problem is, when I click on the first element, it also gets selected.

What I want now, is to prevent the selection of elements unless the select box is unfolded.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tied the unfolding of your dropdown to the click event, but since clicking on a select option selects it by default you should probably use preventDefault (https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop that from happening.

Could you be more specific as to what libraries are being used?

Comment: I use jquery only

Comment: Using `event.preventDefault()` will do.

Comment: unfortunately, event.preventDefault() in the onclick attribute does not seem to doe the job.

Comment: You could try to disable the checkbox unless the box is unfolded, i.e. add "disabled" attribute and remove in the onclick handler

Comment: disabling is a good idea, but it prevents the onclick to get fired as well

Comment: try " pointer-events: none; " .. hope this helps..

Comment: pointer-events:none also prevents the onclick itself to be fired